# Append HTML Files with R

Tags: r, knitr, r-markdown

I'm using `knitr` to create a bunch of HTML files, which can be considered as separate chapters of a master document. After I've created all these chapters, I would like to create one file which has each of these HTML files appended one below the other.

The only way I can think of doing this is to integrate all the templates to create one master template, configure all the paths to images, etc. so that they still work when part of the master template, and then compile that. That sounds like a lot of effort and I'm hoping there exists a better solution.

Any ideas?

Addition on 22 Jan 2014 based on `knit_html` suggestion:

My folder structure is something like this -

```
./Templates/Chapter1.Rmd
./Templates/Chapter2.Rmd
./Client1/Chapter1/Chapter1.html
./Client1/Chapter2/Chapter2.html
./Client2/Chapter1/Chapter1.html
./Client2/Chapter2/Chapter2.html
```

The Rmd doesn't exist in the client folder and is not even aware of the path to knit to until I call it and specifically tell it which folder to knit to.

Now  I need a `./Templates/CompileItAll.Rmd` which can produce a `./Client1/Compiled.html` and a`./Client2/Compiled.html`. I thought the underlying would work, and it does, but it adds a `<!DOCTYPE html>` at the beginning of each child that can be seen in the output. I tried pointing to the `md` file instead, that adds the `rmd` text but omits the sourced images from `./Client/Chapter/*` for some reason -

````
```{r child='../Client1/Chapter1/Chapter1.html'}
```
```{r child='../Client1/Chapter2/Chapter2.html'}
```
````

Am I doing something wrong?

I also tried the code below, that also omitted the sourced images. (I know the paths won't work in this code snipped but I've kept it that way for sake of simplicity, I think the intention is clear)

````
```{r}
setwd('./Client1/Chapter1')
```

```{r child='./Templates/Chapter1.Rmd'}
```
````

Comment: You might also parse your HTML files with the `XML` package (or apply some regular expressions) and add children as needed, but IMHO creating the master document would be a more sane solution.

Comment: `knit_child` and `set_parent` could be one way to go

Comment: @daroczig, you say 'sane solution', and i hear more effort involved :)

Comment: @baptiste, `knit_child` looks promising. Let me try it out and I shall get back on this thread.

Comment: Yes, you can use child documents, e.g. #020: https://github.com/yihui/knitr-examples or https://github.com/yihui/knitr/tree/master/inst/examples/child

Comment: @Yihui, I feel like I've almost got it but I'm stumbling over something right at the finish. I've edited the question to explain the situation. Any suggestions please?

Comment: @baptiste, if you can suggest a solution to the edit I've made, that would be helpful too?

Comment: can you provide minimal examples of your files? I'm not sure what form of knitr document you're using (Rmd, html?). I believe you should pass rmd files as child=..., not the html output.

Comment: I thought that too. But my Rmd file, as you can see from the folder structure, is completely independent of each client. Chapter1.html gets generated when I knit chapter1.Rmd while in the ./Client1/Chapter1 working directory. What do you mean when you say minimal example?

Comment: I tried another thing, which i've added in the question. In a nutshell, I think I'm having problems sourcing images from a variable filepath. The `img src`, I presume, cannot take variables, right? I can read any tables outside of the Rmd and pass them to it so that's okay.

Comment: With a little bit of filename trickery and getting R to move some files after knitting, I have accomplished what I wanted to. @baptiste, if you post `knit_html` as an answer I will accept it.

Comment: However, @Yihui, I would have really liked a cleaner solution. I'm not sure if it is possible to 'variablise' file paths and stuff though. I'm very impressed with `knitr` though, I used to manually pass html code before I discovered your package. Thanks!

Comment: To avoid `<!DOCTYPE html>`, use `knit2html(..., fragment.only = TRUE)` so that you only get the content between `<body></body>`

Comment: Thanks, @Yihui. I have managed a workaround for my currenct activity. I will give that option a whirl the next time.

Answer (score 0):

Not a `knitr` solution but maybe helpful: To simply join a bunch of HTML files you might use [pandoc](http://johnmacfarlane.net/pandoc/). If you enter the code below into the terminal it will join two files into one.

```
pandoc -f html -t html -o file.html file1.html file2.html
```

But I doubt that this approach will give you a nice layout. Its just the concatenated content, nothing more. I agree to @daroczig's comment concerning this.

Comment: Thanks Mark, but I'd prefer an R based solution. Although concatenated content is probably good enough for my purpose.